# Restoring mask to image

Tags: matplotlib, machine-learning, pytorch, python-imaging-library, image-segmentation

My PyTorch model outputs a segmented image with values (0,1,2) for each one of the three classes. During the preparation of the set, I mapped black to 0, red to 1 and white to 2. I have two questions:

1. How can I show what each class represents? for example take a look at the image:
   [image]
   I am currently using the following method to show each class:

   ```
        output = net(input)

        input = input.cpu().squeeze()
        input = transforms.ToPILImage()(input)

        probs = F.softmax(output, dim=1)
        probs = probs.squeeze(0)

        full_mask = probs.squeeze().cpu().numpy()

        fig, (ax0, ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4) = plt.subplots(1, 5, figsize=(20,10), sharey=True)

        ax0.set_title('Input Image')
        ax1.set_title('Background Class')
        ax2.set_title('Neuron Class')
        ax3.set_title('Dendrite Class')
        ax4.set_title('Predicted Mask')

        ax0.imshow(input)
        ax1.imshow(full_mask[0, :, :].squeeze())
        ax2.imshow(full_mask[1, :, :].squeeze())
        ax3.imshow(full_mask[2, :, :].squeeze())

        full_mask = np.argmax(full_mask, 0)
        img = mask_to_image(full_mask)
   ```

But there appears to be shared pixels between the classes, is there a better way to show this (I want the first image to only of the background class, the the second only of the neuron class and the third only of the dendrite class)?

2.My second question is about generating a black, red and white image from the mask, currently the mask is of shape `(512,512)` and has the following values:

```
[[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 2 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 2 2 0]
 ...
 [2 1 2 ... 2 2 2]
 [2 1 2 ... 2 2 2]
 [0 2 0 ... 2 2 2]]
```

And the results look like this:
[image]

Since I am using this code to convert to image:

```
def mask_to_image(mask):
   return Image.fromarray((mask).astype(np.uint8))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But there appears to be shared pixels between the classes, is there a
> better way to show this (I want the first image to only of the
> background class, the the second only of the neuron class and the
> third only of the dendrite class)?

Yes, you can take argmax along `0th` dimension so the one with highest logit (unnormalized probability) will be `1`, rest will be zero:

```
output = net(input)

binary_mask = torch.argmax(output, dim=0).cpu().numpy()
ax.set_title('Neuron Class')
ax.imshow(binary_mask == 0)
```

> My second question is about generating a black, red and white image
> from the mask, currently the mask is of shape (512,512) and has the
> following values

You can spread `[0, 1, 2]` values into the zero-th axis making it channel-wise. Now `[0, 0, 0]` values across all channels for single pixel will be `black`, `[255, 255, 255]` would be white and `[255, 0, 0]` would be red (as PIL is RGB format):

```
import torch

tensor = torch.randint(high=3, size=(512, 512))

red = tensor == 0
white = tensor == 2

zero_channel = red & white

image = torch.stack([zero_channel, white, white]).int().numpy() * 255
Image.fromarray((image).astype(np.uint8))
```

Comment: When I use binary_mask==0 I get an error: Invalid shape (3, 512, 512) for image data, I thought that argmax would condense everything into one channel

Comment: Take `argmax` along dimension which consists of classes (dunno which one it is in your case). So you would get `(512, 512)` tensor for single image after that.

Comment: I solved the problem by applying softmax, however the leaking of classes onto other classes is still a problem :(

Comment: wait, so applying softmax doesnt actually solve the problem? dim = 1 is where my images are (512,512) so I should do it there without applying the softmax?

Comment: Yes, use `argmax` instead of `softmax`. `argmax` takes index with highest value (and the rest is zero), `softmax` normalizes everything to sum into `1` but other classes would have some probability as well (like `0.05`) and that's why your classes leak into another.